# changing UIMapView center location works only on second go

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I have a pretty simple setup - a tableView that shows my many busStops models (busStop has a coordinate) and When i click a cell it pushes a new VC that shows the busStop's location on a MapView (it sets the map's center to the location of the BusStop coordinate).

For some reason - the first time i press any cell the map is not centered (when i push the "back" button and try again it works).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [mainMapView addAnnotation:selectedBusStop];
    [self updateMapCenter:selectedBusStop.coordinate];

}
```

i suspect the map is not loaded yet when i try to call the updateMapCenter method. could this be true? what should i do?
i try adding another call from the viewDidAppear and it solved it partly - however this feels like an overkill. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that iOS 6 changed the timing for loading the map. I used to set the center coordinate in `viewDidLoad`, but it sometimes wouldn't work. I moved it to `viewWillAppear:` and it worked as expected. You might have to think about moving back (as opposed to forward) to the map view, as `viewWillAppear:` would get called again.

There might be a better way (calling `view` on the map view?) but I haven't looked into it further.